# Cannot resolve method 'of' in 'Link' in spring-boot-starter-hateoas

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, spring-hateoas

I'm using the `Hateoas` module to create a `link`. The problem is that the `of` function is used in the official document, but the function cannot be used in my `Link` object. What's the solution?

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.4.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}
...

dependencies {

    compile group: 'org.modelmapper', name: 'modelmapper', version: '0.7.5'

    compile 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.9.2'
    compile 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.9.2'
    compile 'io.springfox:springfox-bean-validators:2.9.2'

    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas'
```

**my problem**

```java
import org.springframework.hateoas.Link;
```

[image]

Comment: Show the import for `Link`. (As an aside, I recommend considering MapStruct instead of ModelMapper; it's much cleaner to work with and about 100x faster.)

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- I added my Link section to my question.

Comment: Check the version of Spring HATEOAS that's being brought in (since you aren't specifying one yourself). `Link.of` was only added in 1.1.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- Can I replace this function without lowering the version of the module?

Comment: You need to _raise_ the version of the module. This should not cause problems.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- Isn't the 'of' function not available because I raised the version? Is my module version wrong?

Comment: *Show the current version of Spring HATEOAS being used.*

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- My module version is the same as the one shown in my question. Isn't it a reference to the spring boot version?

Comment: You have not shown a version of `org.springframework.hateoas:spring-hateoas`. You are probably using 1.0.3, which does not yet have `Link.of`, which is added in 1.1.